# Vue js not triggering onChange

Tags: javascript, vue.js

from the below code, I need a anchor Vue to be converted to Select

The actual code is here

https://github.com/schmich/instascan

I have tried with,

```
<select style="width:100%" v-model="selected" v-on="change:selectCamera">
<option v-for="camera in cameras" v-bind:value="camera.id" >{{ formatName(camera.name) }}</option>
</select>
```

How do I make it respond to onchange event.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#board',
  data: {
    scanner: null,
    activeCameraId: null,
    cameras: [],
    scans: []
  },
  mounted: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({
      video: document.getElementById('preview'),
      mirror: false,
      backgroundScan: false,
      scanPeriod: 2
    });
    self.scanner.addListener('scan', function(content, image) {
      PlaySound();

      var toastElement = $('.toast').first()[0];
      if(toastElement )
      {
        var toastInstance = toastElement.M_Toast;
        toastInstance.remove();
      }

      Materialize.toast(content, 4000);
      //alert(content);
      $.post("https://script.google.com/a/cofm.edu.in/macros/s/AKfycbzObHXjA-gXSyxvyRc5nYVs6yP2sElNpfuWMsIGtLf1yUUXd4n7/exec", {
        "data": content
      }).done(function(data) {
        ;//alert("Data Loaded: " + data)
      });
      self.scans.unshift({
        date: +(Date.now()),
        content: content
      });
    });
    Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function(cameras) {
      self.cameras = cameras;
      if (cameras.length > 0) {
        self.activeCameraId = cameras[0].id;
        self.scanner.start(cameras[0]);
      } else {
        console.error('No cameras found.');
      }
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.error(e);
    });
  },
  methods: {
    formatName: function(name) {
      return name || '(unknown)';
    },
    selectCamera: function(camera) {
      this.activeCameraId = camera.id;
      this.scanner.start(camera);
    }
  }
});

NOTE:The core library is focused on the view layer only, and is easy to pick up and integrate with other libraries or existing projects. On the other hand, Vue is also perfectly capable of powering sophisticated Single-Page Applications when used in combination with modern tooling and supporting libraries.
```

```html
 <div id="app">
     <div class="sidebar">
       <section class="cameras">
         <h2>Cameras</h2>
         <ul>
           <li v-if="cameras.length === 0" class="empty">No cameras found</li>
           <li v-for="camera in cameras">
             <span v-if="camera.id == activeCameraId" :title="formatName(camera.name)" class="active">{{ formatName(camera.name) }}</span>
             <span v-if="camera.id != activeCameraId" :title="formatName(camera.name)">
               <a @click.stop="selectCamera(camera)">{{ formatName(camera.name) }}</a>
             </span>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </section>
       <section class="scans">
         <h2>Scans</h2>
         <ul v-if="scans.length === 0">
           <li class="empty">No scans yet</li>
         </ul>
         <transition-group name="scans" tag="ul">
           <li v-for="scan in scans" :key="scan.date" :title="scan.content">{{ scan.content }}</li>
         </transition-group>
       </section>
     </div>
     <div class="preview-container">
       <video width="75%" height="75%" id="preview"></video>
     </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Why you don't use @change 

<select style="width:100%" v-model="selected" @change="selectCamera">

Comment: You should use :key in the v-for, so the changes can be tracked.
`<option v-model="camera.id" v-for="camera in cameras" :key="camera.id">
{{ formatName(camera.name) }}
</option>`

Comment: I tried, it doesnt work - >      <select style="width:100%" v-model="selected" v-on="change:selectCamera">
                        <option v-model="camera.id" v-for="camera in cameras" :key="camera.id"> {{ formatName(camera.name) }} </option>
                    </select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a huge problem with your v-on. It should be  `v-on:change="selectCamera"`.
Please fix this immediately :-)

Comment: Ok so, `selectCamera()` is a method *inside* your Vue component, and your `v-on:change=""`  is in the template element of this same component. The only thing it makes sense to pass is the event. Everything else is already known. Does that make sense ?

Comment: You can't pass in a variable which isn't available during the time of passing.